Why is it not possible to use OAuth implicit grant flow with client secret or PKCE?
I have a question about OAuth.
If my client application is a web application compatible with the use of a client secret (Or PKCE). So, here the client secret (Or PKCE), is well stored on a server.
In this scenario, why is it not possible to use client secret with the Implicit grant flow? So here there would be directly the client_secret in the token request of the implicit grant flow.
I mean, that would have been better (faster) for these web app, because they wouldn't need anymore to use an Authorization code. And, with the clienr secret, it would be still as secured as with the Authorization code grant flow.
It's just a question to understand Oauth processes.

Given that implicit auth is 100% happening in a browser, a secret would be visible and exposed. It's not a secret at this point and requiring a secret on the implicit flow would give a false sense of security.

What you describe is ,in fact, from my understanding, the commun usage of the implicit grant flow : it is designed for client applications that are not compatible with client secret or PKCE because they can't store that securely.
My question is why : is it not possible to do the same process as the Implict grant flow, for client applications that can handle client secret or PKCE? That would be by adding directly the client secret (or PKCE) to the token request in the Implicit grant flow. That would be better because here the client app wouldn't have to go through an Authorization code.

No, this is incorrect. Implicit grant exists in OAuth2 because 12 years ago not every browser was able to make CORS requests. Implicit is deprecated, insecure and should no longer be used. I would recommend you try to focus on the problems you're seeing with authorization_code and not rely on implicit.
